# Azure SQL Full Text Index initial population slow

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, full-text-indexing

I have a table with approximately 4.7 million records. I created a full text index on it. 
I am experiencing slow initial population of the full text index. 
Initial pricing tier that i had was S1, I upgraded it to S3 but i did not get better performance.

DTU and CPU are not high (usually staying around 0% ), the current velocity is about 175000 records per hour.

What can i do to speed this up?

Thanks in advance.

LE.

I tried same operation on a local instalation of SQL Server 2014, i had no problems with indexing the data.

**Update 14.11.2016**

Output to dm_Exec_requests
session_id  request_id  start_time  status  command sql_handle  statement_start_offset  statement_end_offset    plan_handle database_id user_id connection_id   blocking_session_id wait_type   wait_time   last_wait_type  wait_resource   open_transaction_count  open_resultset_count    transaction_id  context_info    percent_complete    estimated_completion_time   cpu_time    total_elapsed_time  scheduler_id    task_address    reads   writes  logical_reads   text_size   language    date_format date_first  quoted_identifier   arithabort  ansi_null_dflt_on   ansi_defaults   ansi_warnings   ansi_padding    ansi_nulls  concat_null_yields_null transaction_isolation_level lock_timeout    deadlock_priority   row_count   prev_error  nest_level  granted_query_memory    executing_managed_code  group_id    query_hash  query_plan_hash statement_sql_handle    statement_context_id    dop parallel_worker_count   external_script_request_id
90  0   57:45.2 running SELECT  0x020000004D4F6005A3E8119F3DD3297095832ABE63E312F20000000000000000000000000000000000000000  0   66  0x060005004D4F6005D04F998A6E00000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  5   1   70A61674-396D-47EB-82C7-F3C13DAA2AD0    0   NULL    0   MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT       0   1   141037  0x380035003100450039003200350032002D0045003700450032002D0034003600320041002D0039004200390041002D003200310037004400300036003700430032004100360039    0   0   1   1   0   0x7A218C885C2F7437  0   0   228 2147483647  us_english  mdy 7   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   2   -1  0   1   0   0   0   0   2000000026  0xC1681A4180C2C052  0x63AD167562BDAE5D  0x0900A3E8119F3DD3297095832ABE63E312F20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  7   1   NULL    NULL

As i can see on P1 this seems much faster though. It is strange because it is not much more powerfull than S3.

I will mark it as solved because, it seems this is an issue related to service tier levels.

Comment: Can you check wait stats for that query you ran

Comment: select * from sys.dm_exec_requests

Comment: I have only 1 entry:
status command start_time
running SELECT 2016-11-03 13:53:07.710

Comment: please paste the entire ouput

Comment: I am doing same migration now on a different database, this time i set it to P1, i put the output in edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bump up the service tier of Azure database the full text indexing will run much faster than at standard level.

I could not sense a diference between S1 and S3, but P1 versus S3 is much faster.
I do not know the resoning behind this, even though the diference in DTU's is only 25 (S3: 100 DTU, P1: 125 DTU )

Comment: Premium tier is also much more expensive.

Comment: @wBob Yes that is true, but you only need it while it updates the full-text index the first time, future operations are not problematic, and after this the search works also on an S0 price tier